# Bower incompatibilities and resolution issues

Tags: bower

This is a very annoying and unhelpful bower error. "using 1.2.6 which resolved to 1.2.6"? What?...
I'm sure this is causing some issues with my code but I'm not sure why Bower is doing this.

```
Please note that,
    angled-horizon, angular-animate#1.2.6, angular-cookies#1.2.6, angular-mocks#1.2.6, angular-resource#1.2.6, angular-route#1.2.6, angular-sanitize#1.2.6, angular-scenario#1.2.6 depends on angular#1.2.6 which resolved to angular#1.2.6
    angular-bootstrap#0.10.0 depends on angular#>=1 which resolved to angular#1.2.16
    angular-ui-utils#0.1.1 depends on angular#>= 1.0.2 which resolved to angular#1.2.16
    angular-strap#2.0.1 depends on angular#~1.2.10 which resolved to angular#1.2.16

Resort to using angular#1.2.6 which resolved to angular#1.2.6
Code incompatibilities may occur.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that packages listed on the first line have in their `bower.json`'s written "angular#1.2.6". Meaning they want this and only this version. Though the `angular-strap` package wants *at least* version 1.2.10, but accepts patches of it so v1.2.16 would be downloaded.

Bower decided to go with the lower dependency (represented by the string "angular#1.2.6" taken from the `bower.json`), that is to download v1.2.6 of Angular (shortened to "angular#1.2.6"). That should clarify the error message.

It would make sense to assume that the authors of the packages had a reason to require *at least* v1.2.10. My advice is to update packages from the first line if possible. If not, consider a pull request or downgrade the `angular-strap` package.

Comment: Thanks! That made sense.